# why plugin.xml contains xml version tag and eclipse version tag?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

In all my plugin. xml files, I find the below two lines in the beginning.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
```

Can someone please tell me what is the significance of these two lines? 
And does it matter if we remove these lines?

Comment: The first one is a standard XML heading that specifies  the XML version and encoding. The second tells Eclipse about the version of the plugin.xml specification. Why would you want to remove them?

Comment: @greg-449 I asked because I don't know the use of those lines.
Also can we change the eclipse version? why it is coming 3.4 automatically?

Comment: 3.4 is the current version of the plugin.xml specification. The ?xml header is  something you should always put at the start of any XML file.

Comment: Do we need to update this current version to new version? 
Will there be any difference? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: You don't ever need  to do anything with these lines.